# Get fullcalendar event's html element

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I have a list of Fullcalendar events and I need to get the actual HTML elements associated with them, this code retrieves an array of the event objects:

```
var events = handleCalendarEvent('clientEvents', function(_event) {
                 return _event.origin === event.origin &&  isExternalEvent(_event);
             });
```

now I need the actual HTML elements to do some manipulation with them **on hover** (eventrender won't work), looking at the documentation I couldn't find any function to get them.

Comment: I think you should look at `eventRender` function and something like this `eventRender: function(event, element) {  element.find(".fc-event-title") }` and most importantly have l look on http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/

Comment: @Programmmer Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I've updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may still need to use eventRender. As far as I know there is no getElementById type function built in to fullCalendar and, as you probably know, no uniquely identifiable properties are added to the actual element. I would add an id during the callback:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  ...
  eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.data('event-id',event.id);
  },
  ...
})
```

Later on, when you grab your array of event objects, you can use jQuery to find them:

```
var events = handleCalendarEvent('clientEvents', function(_event) {
                 return _event.origin === event.origin &&  isExternalEvent(_event);
             });

var first_event = $("#calendar").find('[data-event-id=' + events[0].id + ']');
```

Comment: This is how I figured it out myself before you commented, still best answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If your events have an id set you can add an id or data tag with eventRender and set the event.id into there, and then eventMouseover you can find the element based on the event.id

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    /* The anchor tag is where the id gets set */
    element.attr('id', 'event-id-' + event.id);
},
eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    var $html = $('#event-id-' + event.id).html();
}
```